# PHP | $_GET & $_POST issue

Tags: php, post, get

do you have any suggestions with my problem. I need to use $_GET and $_POST at the same time. $_GET because I need to get the row which the user want to save I commit the row through the url. $_POST because I need to write the changed input into a csv file. It looks like this:

```
$fileName = '../anfragen.csv';
$lineNum = $_GET['row'];
$arr = file($fileName);
$lineToEdit = $lineNum;

if($_GET['speichern'] != NULL ) {
    $handle = fopen ("../anfragen.csv", "w");
    $arr[$lineToEdit] = utf8_decode($_POST['email']) . ";" . $_POST['gender'] . ";" . "\n");

    // write the array in the csv file
    foreach($arr as $line) {
        fwrite($handle,$line);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Besides the fact you have to make a POST HTTP Request to this page with a url markup like page.php?row=1

Comment: And what is the issue? You can use $_GET and $_POST at the same time because you can send an post request to a url with $_GET parameters eg. http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=10

Comment: I don't think you can `GET` and `POST` on the same request.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) to have `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables in one array.

Comment: There is some use to close vote against existing question for this Q&A website. Just telling.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_REQUEST` instead of $_GET and $_POST.